# Rstudio not recognizing full function. Issue with settings?

Tags: r, rstudio, gbm

My r script is not properly running functions in their entirety.

I am working through the Elith et al. 2008 "A Working Guide to Boosted Regression Trees" but am having difficulty running through the code provided for the guide. When I go to the brt.functions.R script and try to run the first function, my console stops at line 30 after the parameters have been set but before the actual equations are set in the {}. The full function is just over 600 lines long. When I highlight the entire function and tell r to run, it works. So the function isn't the problem, I suspect there is some setting in my rstudio that is causing the bug?

The same issue occurs when I try to run the other functions in the script. My rstudio and r and packages are all up to date. I've tried restarting my session and my laptop but no such luck. I have watched other people run the code just fine, so I'm alone in the issue it seems.
I even tried matching my global options settings to those who don't have the issue but so far that hasn't helped. I have a PC as do others who are able to run the code with no issues.

Here is the code for the function, though I don't have any reason to believe the code is at fault:

```
"gbm.step" <-
function (data,                             # the input dataframe
  gbm.x,                                    # the predictors
  gbm.y,                                    # and response
  offset = NULL,                            # allows an offset to be specified
  fold.vector = NULL,                       # allows a fold vector to be read in for CV with offsets,
  tree.complexity = 1,                      # sets the complexity of individual trees
  learning.rate = 0.01,                     # sets the weight applied to inidivudal trees
  bag.fraction = 0.75,                      # sets the proportion of observations used in selecting variables
  site.weights = rep(1, nrow(data)),        # allows varying weighting for sites
  var.monotone = rep(0, length(gbm.x)),     # restricts responses to individual predictors to monotone 
  n.folds = 10,                             # number of folds
  prev.stratify = TRUE,                     # prevalence stratify the folds - only for p/a data
  family = "bernoulli",                     # family - bernoulli (=binomial), poisson, laplace or gaussian
  n.trees = 50,                             # number of initial trees to fit
  step.size = n.trees,                      # numbers of trees to add at each cycle
  max.trees = 10000,                        # max number of trees to fit before stopping
  tolerance.method = "auto",                # method to use in deciding to stop - "fixed" or "auto"
  tolerance = 0.001,                        # tolerance value to use - if method == fixed is absolute, 
                                            # if auto is multiplier * total mean deviance
  keep.data = FALSE,                        # keep raw data in final model
  plot.main = TRUE,                         # plot hold-out deviance curve
  plot.folds = FALSE,                       # plot the individual folds as well
  verbose = TRUE,                           # control amount of screen reporting
  silent = FALSE,                           # to allow running with no output for simplifying model)
  keep.fold.models = FALSE,                 # keep the fold models from cross valiation
  keep.fold.vector = FALSE,                 # allows the vector defining fold membership to be kept
  keep.fold.fit = FALSE,                    # allows the predicted values for observations from CV to be kept
  ...)                                      # allows for any additional plotting parameters
{
#
# j. leathwick/j. elith - 19th September 2005
#
# version 2.9
#
# function to assess optimal no of boosting trees using k-fold cross validation 
#
# implements the cross-validation procedure described on page 215 of 
# Hastie T, Tibshirani R, Friedman JH (2001) The Elements of Statistical Learning: 
# Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction Springer-Verlag, New York.
#
# divides the data into 10 subsets, with stratification by prevalence if required for pa data
# then fits a gbm model of increasing complexity along the sequence from n.trees to n.trees + (n.steps * step.size)
# calculating the residual deviance at each step along the way
# after each fold processed, calculates the average holdout residual deviance and its standard error
# then identifies the optimal number of trees as that at which the holdout deviance is minimised 
# and fits a model with this number of trees, returning it as a gbm model along with additional information 
# from the cv selection process
#
# updated 13/6/05 to accommodate weighting of sites
#
# updated 19/8/05 to increment all folds simultaneously, allowing the stopping rule
# for the maxinum number of trees to be fitted to be imposed by the data, 
# rather than being fixed in advance
#
# updated 29/8/05 to return cv test statistics, and deviance as mean
# time for analysis also returned via unclass(Sys.time())
#
# updated 5/9/05 to use external function calc.deviance 
# and to return cv test stats via predictions formed from fold models 
# with n.trees = target.trees
#
# updated 15/5/06 to calculate variance of fitted and predicted values across folds
# these can be expected to approximate the variance of fitted values
# as would be estimated for example by bootstrapping
# as these will underestimate the true variance 
# they are corrected by multiplying by (n-1)2/n 
# where n is the number of folds
#
# updated 25/3/07 tp allow varying of bag fraction
#
# requires gbm library from Cran
# requires roc and calibration scripts of J Elith
# requires calc.deviance script of J Elith/J Leathwick
#
#

  require(gbm)

  if (silent) verbose <- FALSE

# initiate timing call

  z1 <- unclass(Sys.time())

# setup input data and assign to position one

  dataframe.name <- deparse(substitute(data))   # get the dataframe name

  data <- eval(data)
  x.data <- eval(data[, gbm.x])                 #form the temporary datasets
  names(x.data) <- names(data)[gbm.x]
  y.data <- eval(data[, gbm.y])
  sp.name <- names(data)[gbm.y]
  if (family == "bernoulli") prevalence <- mean(y.data)

  assign("x.data", x.data, env = globalenv())               #and assign them for later use
  assign("y.data", y.data, env = globalenv())

  offset.name <- deparse(substitute(offset))   # get the dataframe name
  offset = eval(offset)
  print(summary(offset))

  n.cases <- nrow(data)
  n.preds <- length(gbm.x)

  if (!silent) {
    cat("\n","\n","GBM STEP - version 2.9","\n","\n")
    cat("Performing cross-validation optimisation of a boosted regression tree model \n")
    cat("for",sp.name,"with dataframe",dataframe.name,"and using a family of",family,"\n\n")
    cat("Using",n.cases,"observations and",n.preds,"predictors \n\n")
  }

# set up the selector variable either with or without prevalence stratification

  if (is.null(fold.vector)) {

    if (prev.stratify & family == "bernoulli") {
      presence.mask <- data[,gbm.y] == 1
      absence.mask <- data[,gbm.y] == 0
      n.pres <- sum(presence.mask)
      n.abs <- sum(absence.mask)

# create a vector of randomised numbers and feed into presences
      selector <- rep(0,n.cases)
      temp <- rep(seq(1, n.folds, by = 1), length = n.pres)
      temp <- temp[order(runif(n.pres, 1, 100))]
      selector[presence.mask] <- temp

# and then do the same for absences
      temp <- rep(seq(1, n.folds, by = 1), length = n.abs)
      temp <- temp[order(runif(n.abs, 1, 100))]
      selector[absence.mask] <- temp
      }  

    else {  #otherwise make them random with respect to presence/absence
      selector <- rep(seq(1, n.folds, by = 1), length = n.cases)
      selector <- selector[order(runif(n.cases, 1, 100))]
      }
    }
  else {
    if (length(fold.vector) != n.cases) stop("supplied fold vector is of wrong length")
    cat("loading user-supplied fold vector \n\n")
    selector <- eval(fold.vector)
    }

# set up the storage space for results

  pred.values <- rep(0, n.cases)

  cv.loss.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = n.folds, ncol = 1)
  training.loss.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = n.folds, ncol = 1)
  trees.fitted <- n.trees

  model.list <- list(paste("model",c(1:n.folds),sep=""))     # dummy list for the tree models

# set up the initial call to gbm

  if (is.null(offset)) {
    gbm.call <- paste("gbm(y.subset ~ .,data=x.subset, n.trees = n.trees,
    interaction.depth = tree.complexity, shrinkage = learning.rate, 
    bag.fraction = bag.fraction, weights = weight.subset, 
    distribution = as.character(family), var.monotone = var.monotone, 
    verbose = FALSE)", sep="")
    }
  else {
    gbm.call <- paste("gbm(y.subset ~ . + offset(offset.subset),
    data=x.subset, n.trees = n.trees,
    interaction.depth = tree.complexity, shrinkage = learning.rate, 
    bag.fraction = bag.fraction, weights = weight.subset, 
    distribution = as.character(family), var.monotone = var.monotone, 
    verbose = FALSE)", sep="")
    } 

  n.fitted <- n.trees

# calculate the total deviance
               
  y_i <- y.data

  u_i <- sum(y.data * site.weights) / sum(site.weights)
  u_i <- rep(u_i,length(y_i))

  total.deviance <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weights = site.weights, family = family, calc.mean = FALSE)

  mean.total.deviance <- total.deviance/n.cases

  tolerance.test <- tolerance

  if (tolerance.method == "auto") {
     tolerance.test <- mean.total.deviance * tolerance
  }

# now step through the folds setting up the initial call

  if (!silent){ 

    cat("creating",n.folds,"initial models of",n.trees,"trees","\n")
  
    if (prev.stratify & family == "bernoulli") cat("\n","folds are stratified by prevalence","\n","\n")
      else cat("\n","folds are unstratified","\n","\n")
  
    cat ("total mean deviance = ",round(mean.total.deviance,4),"\n","\n")

    cat("tolerance is fixed at ",round(tolerance.test,4),"\n","\n")

    if (tolerance.method != "fixed" & tolerance.method != "auto") {
      cat("invalid argument for tolerance method - should be auto or fixed","\n")
      return()}
  }

  if (verbose) cat("ntrees resid. dev.","\n")

  for (i in 1:n.folds) {

    model.mask <- selector != i  #used to fit model on majority of data
    pred.mask <- selector == i   #used to identify the with-held subset

    y.subset <- y.data[model.mask]
    x.subset <- x.data[model.mask,]
    weight.subset <- site.weights[model.mask]

    if (!is.null(offset)) {
      offset.subset <- offset[model.mask] 
    }
    else {
      offset.subset <- NULL
    }

    model.list[[i]] <- eval(parse(text = gbm.call))

    fitted.values <- model.list[[i]]$fit  #predict.gbm(model.list[[i]], x.subset, type = "response", n.trees = n.trees)
    if (!is.null(offset)) fitted.values <- fitted.values + offset[model.mask]
    if (family == "bernoulli") fitted.values <- exp(fitted.values)/(1 + exp(fitted.values))
    if (family == "poisson") fitted.values <- exp(fitted.values)

    pred.values[pred.mask] <- predict.gbm(model.list[[i]], x.data[pred.mask, ], n.trees = n.trees)
    if (!is.null(offset)) pred.values[pred.mask] <- pred.values[pred.mask] + offset[pred.mask]
    if (family == "bernoulli") pred.values[pred.mask] <- exp(pred.values[pred.mask])/(1 + exp(pred.values[pred.mask]))
    if (family == "poisson") pred.values[pred.mask] <- exp(pred.values[pred.mask])

# calc training deviance

    y_i <- y.subset
    u_i <- fitted.values
    weight.fitted <- site.weights[model.mask]
    training.loss.matrix[i,1] <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weight.fitted, family = family)

# calc holdout deviance

    y_i <- y.data[pred.mask]
    u_i <- pred.values[pred.mask]
    weight.preds <- site.weights[pred.mask]
    cv.loss.matrix[i,1] <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weight.preds, family = family)

  } # end of first loop

# now process until the change in mean deviance is =< tolerance or max.trees is exceeded

  delta.deviance <- 1

  cv.loss.values <- apply(cv.loss.matrix,2,mean)
  if (verbose) cat(n.fitted,"  ",round(cv.loss.values,4),"\n","\n")

  if (!silent) cat("")
  if (!silent) cat("now adding trees...","\n")

  j <- 1

  while (delta.deviance > tolerance.test & n.fitted < max.trees) {  # beginning of inner loop

# add a new column to the results matrice..

    training.loss.matrix <- cbind(training.loss.matrix,rep(0,n.folds))
    cv.loss.matrix <- cbind(cv.loss.matrix,rep(0,n.folds))

    n.fitted <- n.fitted + step.size
    trees.fitted <- c(trees.fitted,n.fitted)
  
    j <- j + 1
 
    for (i in 1:n.folds) {

      model.mask <- selector != i  #used to fit model on majority of data
      pred.mask <- selector == i   #used to identify the with-held subset

      y.subset <- y.data[model.mask]
      x.subset <- x.data[model.mask,]
      weight.subset <- site.weights[model.mask]
      if (!is.null(offset)) {
        offset.subset <- offset[model.mask] 
      }

      model.list[[i]] <- gbm.more(model.list[[i]], weights = weight.subset, step.size)

      fitted.values <- model.list[[i]]$fit # predict.gbm(model.list[[i]],x.subset, type = "response", n.trees = n.fitted) 
      if (!is.null(offset)) fitted.values <- fitted.values + offset[model.mask]
      if (family == "bernoulli") fitted.values <- exp(fitted.values)/(1 + exp(fitted.values))
      if (family == "poisson") fitted.values <- exp(fitted.values)

      pred.values[pred.mask] <- predict.gbm(model.list[[i]], x.data[pred.mask, ], n.trees = n.fitted)
      if (!is.null(offset)) pred.values[pred.mask] <- pred.values[pred.mask] + offset[pred.mask]
      if (family == "bernoulli") pred.values[pred.mask] <- exp(pred.values[pred.mask])/(1 + exp(pred.values[pred.mask]))
      if (family == "poisson") pred.values[pred.mask] <- exp(pred.values[pred.mask])
   
# calculate training deviance

      y_i <- y.subset
      u_i <- fitted.values
      weight.fitted <- site.weights[model.mask]
      training.loss.matrix[i,j] <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weight.fitted, family = family)

# calc holdout deviance

      u_i <- pred.values[pred.mask]
      y_i <- y.data[pred.mask]
      weight.preds <- site.weights[pred.mask]
      cv.loss.matrix[i,j] <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weight.preds, family = family)

    }  # end of inner loop

    cv.loss.values <- apply(cv.loss.matrix,2,mean)

    if (j < 5) {
      if (cv.loss.values[j] > cv.loss.values[j-1]) {
        if (!silent) cat("restart model with a smaller learning rate or smaller step size...")
        return()
      }
    }

      if (j >= 20) {   #calculate stopping rule value
        test1 <- mean(cv.loss.values[(j-9):j])
        test2 <- mean(cv.loss.values[(j-19):(j-9)])
        delta.deviance <- test2 - test1
      }

      if (verbose) cat(n.fitted," ",round(cv.loss.values[j],4),"\n")    

  } # end of while loop

# now begin process of calculating optimal number of trees

  training.loss.values <- apply(training.loss.matrix,2,mean)

  cv.loss.ses <- rep(0,length(cv.loss.values))
  cv.loss.ses <- sqrt(apply(cv.loss.matrix,2,var)) / sqrt(n.folds)

# find the target holdout deviance

  y.bar <- min(cv.loss.values) 

# plot out the resulting curve of holdout deviance 

  if (plot.main) {

    y.min <- min(cv.loss.values - cv.loss.ses)  #je added multiplier 10/8/05
    y.max <- max(cv.loss.values + cv.loss.ses)  #je added multiplier 10/8/05 }

    if (plot.folds) {
      y.min <- min(cv.loss.matrix)
      y.max <- max(cv.loss.matrix) }

      plot(trees.fitted, cv.loss.values, type = 'l', ylab = "holdout deviance",
          xlab = "no. of trees", ylim = c(y.min,y.max), ...)
      abline(h = y.bar, col = 2)

      lines(trees.fitted, cv.loss.values + cv.loss.ses, lty=2)  
      lines(trees.fitted, cv.loss.values - cv.loss.ses, lty=2)  

      if (plot.folds) {
        for (i in 1:n.folds) {
          lines(trees.fitted, cv.loss.matrix[i,],lty = 3)
      }
    }
  }
    
# identify the optimal number of trees 

  target.trees <- trees.fitted[match(TRUE,cv.loss.values == y.bar)]

  if(plot.main) {
    abline(v = target.trees, col=3)
    title(paste(sp.name,", d - ",tree.complexity,", lr - ",learning.rate, sep=""))
  }

# estimate the cv deviance and test statistics
# includes estimates of the standard error of the fitted values added 2nd may 2005

  cv.deviance.stats <- rep(0, n.folds)
  cv.roc.stats <- rep(0, n.folds)
  cv.cor.stats <- rep(0, n.folds)
  cv.calibration.stats <- matrix(0, ncol=5, nrow = n.folds)
  if (family == "bernoulli") threshold.stats <- rep(0, n.folds)

  fitted.matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.cases, ncol = n.folds)  # used to calculate se's
  fold.fit <- rep(0,n.cases)

  for (i in 1:n.folds) {

    pred.mask <- selector == i   #used to identify the with-held subset
    model.mask <- selector != i  #used to fit model on majority of data

    fits <- predict.gbm(model.list[[i]], x.data[model.mask, ], n.trees = target.trees)
    if (!is.null(offset)) fits <- fits + offset[model.mask]
    if (family == "bernoulli") fits <- exp(fits)/(1 + exp(fits))
    if (family == "poisson") fits <- exp(fits)
    fitted.matrix[model.mask,i] <- fits

    fits <- predict.gbm(model.list[[i]], x.data[pred.mask, ], n.trees = target.trees)
    if (!is.null(offset)) fits <- fits + offset[pred.mask]
    fold.fit[pred.mask] <- fits  # store the linear predictor values
    if (family == "bernoulli") fits <- exp(fits)/(1 + exp(fits))
    if (family == "poisson") fits <- exp(fits)
    fitted.matrix[pred.mask,i] <- fits

    y_i <- y.data[pred.mask] 
    u_i <- fitted.matrix[pred.mask,i]  #pred.values[pred.mask]
    weight.preds <- site.weights[pred.mask]

    cv.deviance.stats[i] <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weight.preds, family = family)

    cv.cor.stats[i] <- cor(y_i,u_i)

    if (family == "bernoulli") {
      cv.roc.stats[i] <- roc(y_i,u_i)
      cv.calibration.stats[i,] <- calibration(y_i,u_i,"binomial")
      threshold.stats[i] <- approx(ppoints(u_i), sort(u_i,decreasing = T), prevalence)$y
    }

    if (family == "poisson") {
      cv.calibration.stats[i,] <- calibration(y_i,u_i,"poisson")
    }
  }

  fitted.vars <- apply(fitted.matrix,1, var, na.rm = TRUE)

# now calculate the mean and se's for the folds

  cv.dev <- mean(cv.deviance.stats, na.rm = TRUE)
  cv.dev.se <- sqrt(var(cv.deviance.stats)) / sqrt(n.folds)

  cv.cor <- mean(cv.cor.stats, na.rm = TRUE)
  cv.cor.se <- sqrt(var(cv.cor.stats, use = "complete.obs")) / sqrt(n.folds)

  cv.roc <- 0.0
  cv.roc.se <- 0.0 

  if (family == "bernoulli") {
    cv.roc <- mean(cv.roc.stats,na.rm=TRUE)
    cv.roc.se <- sqrt(var(cv.roc.stats, use = "complete.obs")) / sqrt(n.folds)  
    cv.threshold <- mean(threshold.stats, na.rm = T)
    cv.threshold.se <- sqrt(var(threshold.stats, use = "complete.obs")) / sqrt(n.folds)  
  }
 
  cv.calibration <- 0.0
  cv.calibration.se <- 0.0

  if (family == "poisson" | family == "bernoulli") {
    cv.calibration <- apply(cv.calibration.stats,2,mean)
    cv.calibration.se <- apply(cv.calibration.stats,2,var)
    cv.calibration.se <- sqrt(cv.calibration.se) / sqrt(n.folds) }

# fit the final model

  if (is.null(offset)) {
    gbm.call <- paste("gbm(y.data ~ .,data=x.data, n.trees = target.trees,
    interaction.depth = tree.complexity, shrinkage = learning.rate, 
    bag.fraction = bag.fraction, weights = site.weights, 
    distribution = as.character(family), var.monotone = var.monotone, 
    verbose = FALSE)", sep="")
    }
  else {
    gbm.call <- paste("gbm(y.data ~ . + offset(offset),data=x.data, n.trees = target.trees,
    interaction.depth = tree.complexity, shrinkage = learning.rate, 
    bag.fraction = bag.fraction, weights = site.weights, 
    distribution = as.character(family), var.monotone = var.monotone, 
    verbose = FALSE)", sep="")
    } 

  if (!silent) cat("fitting final gbm model with a fixed number of ",target.trees," trees for ",sp.name,"\n") 

  gbm.object <- eval(parse(text = gbm.call))

  best.trees <- target.trees

#extract fitted values and summary table
  
  gbm.summary <- summary(gbm.object,n.trees = target.trees, plotit = FALSE)

  fits <- predict.gbm(gbm.object,x.data,n.trees = target.trees)
  if (!is.null(offset)) fits <- fits + offset
  if (family == "bernoulli") fits <- exp(fits)/(1 + exp(fits))
  if (family == "poisson") fits <- exp(fits)
  fitted.values <- fits

  y_i <- y.data
  u_i <- fitted.values
  resid.deviance <- calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weights = site.weights, family = family, calc.mean = FALSE)

  self.cor <- cor(y_i,u_i)
  self.calibration <- 0.0
  self.roc <- 0.0

  if (family == "bernoulli") {  # do this manually as we need the residuals
    deviance.contribs <- (y_i * log(u_i)) + ((1-y_i) * log(1 - u_i))
    residuals <- sqrt(abs(deviance.contribs * 2))
    residuals <- ifelse((y_i - u_i) < 0, 0 - residuals, residuals)
    self.roc <- roc(y_i,u_i)
    self.calibration <- calibration(y_i,u_i,"binomial")
  }

  if (family == "poisson") {   # do this manually as we need the residuals
    deviance.contribs <- ifelse(y_i == 0, 0, (y_i * log(y_i/u_i))) - (y_i - u_i)
    residuals <- sqrt(abs(deviance.contribs * 2))
    residuals <- ifelse((y_i - u_i) < 0, 0 - residuals, residuals)
    self.calibration <- calibration(y_i,u_i,"poisson")
  }

  if (family == "gaussian" | family == "laplace") {
    residuals <- y_i - u_i
  }

  mean.resid.deviance <- resid.deviance/n.cases

  z2 <- unclass(Sys.time())
  elapsed.time.minutes <- round((z2 - z1)/ 60,2)  #calculate the total elapsed time

  if (verbose) {
    cat("\n")
    cat("mean total deviance =", round(mean.total.deviance,3),"\n")
    cat("mean residual deviance =", round(mean.resid.deviance,3),"\n","\n")
    cat("estimated cv deviance =", round(cv.dev,3),"; se =",
      round(cv.dev.se,3),"\n","\n")
    cat("training data correlation =",round(self.cor,3),"\n")
    cat("cv correlation = ",round(cv.cor,3),"; se =",round(cv.cor.se,3),"\n","\n")
    if (family == "bernoulli") {
      cat("training data ROC score =",round(self.roc,3),"\n")
      cat("cv ROC score =",round(cv.roc,3),"; se =",round(cv.roc.se,3),"\n","\n")
    }
    cat("elapsed time - ",round(elapsed.time.minutes,2),"minutes","\n")
  }

  if (n.fitted == max.trees & !silent) {
    cat("\n","########### warning ##########","\n","\n")
    cat("maximum tree limit reached - results may not be optimal","\n")
    cat("  - refit with faster learning rate or increase maximum number of trees","\n") 
  }
    
# now assemble data to be returned

  gbm.detail <- list(dataframe = dataframe.name, gbm.x = gbm.x, predictor.names = names(x.data), 
    gbm.y = gbm.y, response.name = sp.name, offset = offset.name, family = family, tree.complexity = tree.complexity, 
    learning.rate = learning.rate, bag.fraction = bag.fraction, cv.folds = n.folds, 
    prev.stratification = prev.stratify, max.fitted = n.fitted, n.trees = target.trees, 
    best.trees = target.trees, train.fraction = 1.0, tolerance.method = tolerance.method, 
    tolerance = tolerance, var.monotone = var.monotone, date = date(), 
    elapsed.time.minutes = elapsed.time.minutes)

  training.stats <- list(null = total.deviance, mean.null = mean.total.deviance, 
    resid = resid.deviance, mean.resid = mean.resid.deviance, correlation = self.cor, 
    discrimination = self.roc, calibration = self.calibration)

  cv.stats <- list(deviance.mean = cv.dev, deviance.se = cv.dev.se, 
    correlation.mean = cv.cor, correlation.se = cv.cor.se,
    discrimination.mean = cv.roc, discrimination.se = cv.roc.se,
    calibration.mean = cv.calibration, calibration.se = cv.calibration.se)

  if (family == "bernoulli") {
    cv.stats$cv.threshold <- cv.threshold
    cv.stats$cv.threshold.se <- cv.threshold.se
  }

  rm(x.data,y.data, envir = globalenv())           #finally, clean up the temporary dataframes

# and assemble results for return

  gbm.object$gbm.call <- gbm.detail
  gbm.object$fitted <- fitted.values
  gbm.object$fitted.vars <- fitted.vars
  gbm.object$residuals <- residuals
  gbm.object$contributions <- gbm.summary
  gbm.object$self.statistics <- training.stats
  gbm.object$cv.statistics <- cv.stats
  gbm.object$weights <- site.weights
  gbm.object$trees.fitted <- trees.fitted
  gbm.object$training.loss.values <- training.loss.values
  gbm.object$cv.values <- cv.loss.values
  gbm.object$cv.loss.ses <- cv.loss.ses
  gbm.object$cv.loss.matrix <- cv.loss.matrix
  gbm.object$cv.roc.matrix <- cv.roc.stats

  if (keep.fold.models) gbm.object$fold.models <- model.list
  else gbm.object$fold.models <- NULL

  if (keep.fold.vector) gbm.object$fold.vector <- selector
  else gbm.object$fold.vector <- NULL

  if (keep.fold.fit) gbm.object$fold.fit <- fold.fit
  else gbm.object$fold.fit <- NULL

  return(gbm.object)  
}
```

Any ideas as to what settings would help correct the issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: “The full function is just over 600 lines long. […] I don't have any reason to believe the code is at fault” — Oh no, the code *is* at fault. Horrendously at fault.

Comment: @KonradRudolph haha it is certainly at fault for some things but not for this particular issue

Comment: Setting aside the potential need for refactoring, what is indicating to you that the function is not being properly stored into the environment? I have just run it on my own end, and while the console doesn't run through the entire code base, it is shown on my end to be properly stored in the environment.

Comment: Having said that, I can't test the function because it seems that it needs some other scripts (roc, calibration, calc.deviance) in order to execute.

Comment: 16 year old code? Maybe you don't want your R version and packages up to date...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).